# How to solve: COM class factory for component with CLSID error 80080005 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rtf, dcom

I'm stuck with this:

This is my scenario:

I'm creating a website that the user select a Word document, a webservice save it in RTF format, and then I read the RTF document to show in Crystal Reports.

First the user select the document (.doc, .docx) to save. (Click a button to open a file...)
Then, the website calls a webservice that has permissions to write, the selected file, into another server (file's server) with a different name and saving as .rtf format to use in crystal reports.
And here is when the error comes:

```
COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005
```

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2, and the webservice has the permissions to write, the identity of the Application Pool (WsOps) is a user with permissions to write.
The server has installed Office 2007 and VS2010 already if it needs the famous Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14.

Y tried [this code in ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1093228.aspx/1) and nothing.

Some help is appreciated.

Comment: does the app pool have "Enable 32-bit applications" turned on?

Comment: Yes, it has enabled the 32-bit applications.